# What is the best file structure for several projects and 1 virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a number of django projects organized with the following directory structure using win7 (I'm using GIT_BASH/mingw for my command line) :

```
envs--r1--project1
        --project2

pPython275--
```

My files are on portable flash drive which is in an adjacent directory to 'envs'

I want to end up with the different projects having a common environment that I activate  from each projects root directory using :

```
$ source ../Scripts/activate
```

Is this file structure OK or do I need to make changes to create a common virtualenv using the python interpreter at:

f:/pPython275/python.exe

Answer (score 2):

**Personal Opinion**
I personally prefer keeping my projects outside the virtualenv, which helps me if i need to clone (copy) the virtualenv.

the structure I use is

```
envs--r1--
    --Library
    --Scripts--python.exe
projects--
    --project1
    --project2
pPython275--
```

You could activate your venv from anywhere. and relative path like you specified would work too
    `$ source ../envs/r1/Scripts/activate`

Comment: Or even use [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my original question . There are no Lib or Scripts folders in r1. I need to use the pPython275/python.exe interpreter because its on a flash drive. How would the pPython275/python.exe interpreter be set up as the interpreter for the r1 virtualenv?